# Pass data to Mail Job/Queue - Lumen/Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, lumen

I'm using `Lumen` and want to know how to pass `data` to my `job` class.
I have my `job` class like below;

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer;

class TestEmailJob extends Job
{
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //

    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(Mailer $mailer)
    {
        //
        $data; // I want to pass this from my function
        $mailer->queue('emails.emailtemplate', $data , function ($message) {
            $message->from('support@xxx.com', 'Laravel');

            $message->to('xxx@gmail.com')->cc('xxx@yahoo.co.uk');
        });
    }
}
```

I then have a function to push the job on the queue;

```
public function emailTest () {

    $data = ['user' => $user];

    Queue::push(new TestEmailJob);
}
```

How can I pass `$data` and receive it and use it in the `job` class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can instantiate the variable by passing to the constructor

```
class TestEmailJob extends Job implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue;

    protected $data;


    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        // $this->data;
    }
}
```

Now from the Controller, you can call it like:

`$this->dispatch(new TestEmailJob($data));`

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#writing-job-classes

Comment: And I just pass it like this? `Queue::push(new TestEmailJob($data));`

Comment: You can dispatch it to the queue from your controller like this: 
`$this->dispatch(new TestEmailJob($data));`

Comment: Why not just use `Mail::queue()` ?

Comment: @BenSwinburne Depends if you have Facades enabled. I use `Mail::queue()` also

Comment: @moh.ABK I meant if you're using `$mailer->queue()` or equivalent, why are you queuing a job which then queues the mail? Why not just queue the mail directly from `emailTest()`. I also originally meant to comment on the Question, not this answer. Apologies.

Comment: @BenSwinburne that was a typo on my side